# Why is if statement evaluating false for an operator overloading function?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
class cid
{
    int caseNo,agentNo;
public:
    cid(){}
    cid(int caseNo)
    {
        this->caseNo = caseNo;
    }
    void operator<<(int x)
    {
        this->agentNo = x;
    }
    void operator>>(int x)
    {
        this->agentNo = 0;
        if(x == this->caseNo)
            cout << "\nhello";
        else
            cout << "\nbye";
    }
    void display(void)
    {
        cout << "\ncase num is  : " << caseNo << " agent num is : " << agentNo;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cid daya(1),praduman(7);
    daya << 10;
    praduman << 1550;
    daya.display();
    praduman.display();
    daya >> 10;
    praduman >> 1550;
    daya.display();
    praduman.display();

    cout << "\npress enter to continue...";
    cin.ignore();cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
case num is  : 1 agent num is : 10
case num is  : 7 agent num is : 1550
bye
bye
case num is  : 1 agent num is : 0
case num is  : 7 agent num is : 0
press enter to continue...
```

I was trying to evaluate the caseNo and x to see if it is assigned if the number is same then make the agentNo to 0 but to debug i tried to compare it with 1 as already assigned as case number it evaluates as false plz help

Comment: Related:  https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/   You should probably put a breakpoint in your debugger where you think something's going wrong and look at the variables

Comment: Aside: you've overloaded `>>` to do something very ... very strange

Comment: Aside, I recommend that you do not use `operator<<` and `operator>>` for these non-I/O and non-Bitshift member functions.  Only serves to confuse.

Comment: `daya.caseNo` is `1` and `praduman.caseNo` is `7`, you never change it and compare them with `10` and `1550`. Why should they be equal? https://ideone.com/uLVSih

Comment: I don't understand the problem. The program does exactly what I would suspect

Comment: @Eljay: I would say, `operator<<` is okay, because it behaves like a stringstream.

Comment: The `daya >> 10;` should output "bye".  If it were `daya >> 1;` then it will output "hello".

Comment: okay i got my mistake thx guys i was searching it for about 2hrs

Answer (score 0):

In line

```
cid daya(1),praduman(7);
```

you set `daya.caseNo = 1` and `praduman.caseNo = 7`. With

```
daya << 10;
praduman << 1550;
```

you set `daya.agentNo = 10` and `praduman.agentNo = 1550`. That's exactly the output of

```
daya.display();
praduman.display();
```

With `daya >> 10;` you set `daya.agentNo = 0` and check if `if(x == this->caseNo)`. The value of `x` is 10 and `daya.caseNo` is `1`. So this yields `false` and outputs `Bye`. Same story for `praduman >> 1550;`